# How do i enable developer mode in google chrome (in mac)

Tags: google-chrome

How do i enable the developer mode in google chrome browser (mac)

I cannot find answer

Code is not applicable

Output is also not applicable

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Chrome Browser
2. Click on : button
3. Select Settings
4. Click Extensions
5. Toggle the Developer Mode option